# My command prompt opens before the click on a button

Tags: javascript

I have 3 prompts, the first is to enter `hours` and the second `minutes`, when the user click on button:`add n minutes`, I would like to display a third prompt by proposing several minutes.

[image]

[image]

My problem is that my command prompt is executed before the clik on button.

My HTML

```
<body >
   <h1>Exercise 8</h1>
   <label>Hours : <input type="text" id='h' /></label>
   <label>Minutes : <input type="text" id='m' /></label>
   <button id="btn1">Pass 1 minute</button>
   <button id="btn2">Add n minutes</button>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

My JS

```
var hours = parseInt(prompt('Enter your hours please : '));
var minutes = parseInt(prompt('Enter your minutes please : '));

var btnPassOneMinute = document.getElementById('btn1');
var btnPass_N_Minute = document.getElementById('btn2');

/*if (hours != null) {
  main();
}*/

btnPassOneMinute.addEventListener('click', addOneMinute);
btnPass_N_Minute.addEventListener('click', add_N_Minute);

main();
addOneMinute();
add_N_Minute();

function main(){

    if(minutes > 59){
        minutes = 0;
        hours += 1;
    }

    if(hours > 23){
        hours = 0;
    }

    document.getElementById('h').value = hours;
    document.getElementById('m').value = minutes;
}

function addOneMinute(){

    main();

    minutes += 1;
}

function add_N_Minute(){

    //main();
    var addMinute = parseInt(prompt('Add your minutes : '));


    minutes += addMinute; 

    if(addMinute > 59){
        minutes = 0;
    }

    if(minutes > 59){
        minutes = 0;
        hours += 1;
    }

    if(hours > 23){
        hours = 0;
    }

    document.getElementById('h').value = hours;
    document.getElementById('m').value = minutes;


}
```

```js
var hours = parseInt(prompt('Enter your hours please : '));
var minutes = parseInt(prompt('Enter your minutes please : '));

var btnPassOneMinute = document.getElementById('btn1');
var btnPass_N_Minute = document.getElementById('btn2');

/*if (hours != null) {
  main();
}*/

btnPassOneMinute.addEventListener('click', addOneMinute);
btnPass_N_Minute.addEventListener('click', add_N_Minute);

main();
addOneMinute();
add_N_Minute();

function main(){

 if(minutes > 59){
  minutes = 0;
  hours += 1;
 }

 if(hours > 23){
  hours = 0;
 }

    document.getElementById('h').value = hours;
    document.getElementById('m').value = minutes;
}

function addOneMinute(){

    main();

    minutes += 1;
}

function add_N_Minute(){

 //main();
    var addMinute = parseInt(prompt('Add your minutes : '));

 
    minutes += addMinute; 

    if(addMinute > 59){
     minutes = 0;
    }

    if(minutes > 59){
  minutes = 0;
  hours += 1;
 }

 if(hours > 23){
  hours = 0;
 }

    document.getElementById('h').value = hours;
    document.getElementById('m').value = minutes;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cours JavaScript</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="cours.css">
    </head>
    
    <body >
        <h1>Exercise 8</h1>
        <label>Hours : <input type="text" id='h' /></label>
        <label>Minutes : <input type="text" id='m' /></label>
        <button id="btn1">Pass 1 minute</button>
        <button id="btn2">Add n minutes</button>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you...

Comment: remove addOneMinute();
add_N_Minute(); from inline code

Comment: call function onclick function

Comment: _"My problem is that my command prompt is executed before the clik on button"_ - Yes, because: `var hours = parseInt(prompt(...)); var minutes = parseInt(prompt(...));` o.O

Comment: @mplungjan: Yes, thank you ^^

Comment: And of course the inline prompts @Andreas pointed out

Comment: Also you have too many of these tests: minutes += addMinute; 

    if(addMinute > 59){
     minutes = 0;
    }

    if(minutes > 59){